# Symfony 4 RepeatedType validation not working

Tags: php, forms, symfony, passwords, repeat

i have a problem creating a simple registration form in Symfony 4.
For the password i use the RepeatedType provided by Symfony, but typing in two different password doesn´t produce any errors and it is still possible to submit the form.

```
->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields do not match.',
            'options' => [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ],
            'required' => $options['req'],
            'first_options'  => ['label' => 'New Password'],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat New Password'],
        ])
```

Did i make any mistake adding the Password field with the FormBuilder or might the mistake be even located somewhere else?

This is how i use the NewUserType:

```
$form = $this->createForm(NewUserType::class, new User(), [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('createUser')
    ]);
    return $this->render('admin/account-management.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'accounts' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll(),
        'user' => $user
    ]);
```

This is how i insert the form into HTML using twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Comment: Do you call $form->isValid() somewhere? It triggers the validation.

Comment: Please provide full controller action

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isSubmitted` to check if form was submitted and `isValid` method on `$form` to validate it. Also you don't need another route for creating user.

```php
$form = $this->createForm(NewUserType::class, new User(), [
    // this isn't necessary
    //'action' => $this->generateUrl('createUser') 
]);

if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // this should contain your code from 'createUser' action
}

return $this->render('admin/account-management.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'accounts' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findAll(),
    'user' => $user
]);
```